# Swift - add colored top border for selected tab

Tags: ios, swift, border, uitabview

How can I add such a top border color on the selected tab in Swift 3 like in the following image?

[image]

Comment: change the tab images(top border) for selected condition.

Comment: Selected tab - UITabBar or UISegmentControl ?